# Can I have a polymorphic response in Nestjs OpenAPI?

Tags: nestjs, openapi

Using Nestjs OpenAPI module, I can specify the response type using a decorator like so:

```js
@Controller('app')
class MyController {
  @Get()
  @ApiResponse({ status: 200, description: 'Success', type: MyDto })
  getThing() {
    // code here
  }
}
```

However, the documentation does not specify how to have a polymorphic response type (or in OpenAPI terms a `oneOf` response type). E.g., in the example below I would want to have my response type be `oneOf: [MyDto, MyOtherDto]`:

```js
@Controller('app')
class MyController {
  @Get()
  @ApiResponse({ status: 200, description: 'Success', type: MyDto }) // What do do for type here?
  getThing(): MyDto | MyOtherDto {
    // code here
  }
}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so not sure if this is the best/easiest way, but a "raw schema definition" can be supplied for the `@ApiResponse()` decorator, like so:

```js
@Controller('app')
class MyController {
  @Get()
  @ApiResponse({
    status: 200,
    description: 'Success',
    schema: {
      oneOf: [
        { $ref: getSchemaPath(MyDto) },
        { $ref: getSchemaPath(MyOtherDto) },
      ]
    }
  })
  getThing(): MyDto | MyOtherDto {
    // code here
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In case your polymorphic class has a discriminator - you can take it one step further with the following code:

```js
enum DtoType {
  MY_DTO = 'MY_DTO',
  MY_OTHER_DTO = 'MY_OTHER_DTO',
}

@Controller('app')
class MyController {
  @Get()
  @ApiResponse({
    status: 200,
    description: 'Success',
    schema: {
      oneOf: [
        { $ref: getSchemaPath(MyDto) },
        { $ref: getSchemaPath(MyOtherDto) }
      ],
    discriminator: {
      propertyName: 'type',
      mapping: {
        [DtoType.MY_DTO]: 'MyDto',
        [DtoType.MY_OTHER_DTO]: 'MyOtherDto',
      },
  },
}
  })
  getThing(): MyDto | MyOtherDto {
    // code here
  }
}
```